# Are infinispan versions 12.0.x and 13.0.x are compatible with Spring Boot 2.4.13?

Tags: spring-boot, infinispan

Spring Boot `2.4.13` comes with several infinispan libraries of version `11.0.11.Final`, which is affected by vulnerability (https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2021-31917).
This vulnerability is only fixed in versions `12.0.1` and above. But since those versions are different major versions when compared to `11.0.11`, the question arises - are they compatible with Spring Boot `2.4.13`?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was resolved only in 11.0.12.Final and 12.1.4.Final. It was not fixed on any of the 12.0.x releases.
Infinispan 12.1.x is compatible with Spring Boot 2.4.

https://issues.redhat.com/browse/ISPN-13072

Additionally: the bug only affects the `org.infinispan:infinispan-server-rest` component which the Spring Boot components *do not* depend on.